Custom Dynamic Tag in Elementor not showing image
Hi I am trying to add dynamic tags to the wordpress "image" widget, so that I will be able to choose custom featured image: second-featured-image and third-featured-image.
These second and third images are working, I have created it a custom code and if I retrieve them with normal code i see them appearing, so meaning the get saved to the database.
I have it almost working, but the most important, showing the image on the front end is not working.
I have created a folder called: custom-efi-dynamic-tags in the plugin folder.
In this folder I have created file called custom-efi-dynamic-tags.php
and a folder calles includes, where I have my second featured tag code in the file:
class-second-featured-image-tag.php
I am wondering why the image is not loading.
I have tried codes and read the documentation of elementor on this topic, but I am somehow not able to get the images.
    <?php
    /**
     * Plugin Name: Custom EFI Dynamic Tags
     * Description: Adds custom dynamic tags for Elementor for second and third featured images.
     * Version: 1.0.0
     * Author: Your Name
     * Text Domain: custom-efi-dynamic-tag
     */
    
     namespace Custom_Efi_Dynamic_Tag;
     
     use Elementor\Plugin;
     use Elementor\Core\DynamicTags\Tag;
     
     class Efi_Plugin {
     
         private static $_instance = null;
     
         public static function instance() {
             if ( is_null( self::$_instance ) ) {
                 self::$_instance = new self();
             }
             return self::$_instance;
         }
     
         public function __construct() {
             add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'init' ) );
         }
     
         public function init() {
             add_action( 'elementor/dynamic_tags/register_tags', [ $this, 'register_dynamic_tags' ] );
         }
     
         public function register_dynamic_tags( $dynamic_tags ) {
            error_log('Registering dynamic tags...');
            \Elementor\Plugin::$instance->dynamic_tags->register_group( 'custom-dynamic-tags', [
                'title' => 'My Custom Dynamic Tags'
            ]);
        
            include_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/class-second-featured-image-tag.php' );
            include_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/class-third-featured-image-tag.php' );
        
            $dynamic_tags->register_tag( 'Custom_Efi_Dynamic_Tag\Second_Featured_Image_Tag' );
            $dynamic_tags->register_tag( 'Custom_Efi_Dynamic_Tag\Third_Featured_Image_Tag' );
        
            error_log('Dynamic tags registered.');
        }
        
     }
     
     if ( ! function_exists( 'Plugin' ) ) {
         function Efi_Plugin() {
             return Efi_Plugin::instance();
         }
     }
     
     Efi_Plugin();

and my second featured images looks like this:

<?php
namespace Custom_Efi_Dynamic_Tag;

use Elementor\Core\DynamicTags\Tag;
use Elementor\Modules\DynamicTags\Module;

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

class Second_Featured_Image_Tag extends Tag {

    public function get_name() {
        return 'second-featured-image';
    }

    public function get_title() {
        return __( 'Second Featured Image', 'custom-efi-dynamic-tag' );
    }

    public function get_group() {
        return 'custom-dynamic-tags';
    }

    public function get_categories() {
        return [ Module::IMAGE_CATEGORY ];
    }

    protected function register_controls() {
        // No additional controls required for this dynamic tag.
    }

    public function render() {
        $second_featured_image_url = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_second_featured_image', true );
        if ( empty( $second_featured_image_url ) ) {
            error_log('No URL found for second featured image.');
            return;
        }
    
        error_log('Rendering image: ' . $second_featured_image_url);
    
        echo '<img src="' . esc_url( $second_featured_image_url ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr__( 'Second Featured Image', 'custom-efi-dynamic-tag' ) . '">';
    }
    
}

What am I missing that the images are not showing if i choose them from the dymanic tag?
Thanks already.
